# BeautifulSoup - Find link in this HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's my code to get html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = "https://blahblah.com"
ua = UserAgent()
ran_header = ua.random
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data=None,headers={'User-Agent': ran_header})
uClient = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

html_source = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
results = html_source.findAll("a",{"onclick":"googleTag('click-listings-item-image');"})
```

From here `results` contains various listings containing different info. If I then `print(results[0])`:

```
<a href="https://blahblah.com//link//asdfqwersdf" onclick="googleTag('click-listings-item-image');">
    <div class="results-panel-new col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 text-center thumb-table-cell">
                <span class="eq-table-new text-center"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="//images/120x90/7831a94157234bc6.jpg" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-1 text-center thumb-table-cell">
                <span class="eq-table-new text-center"><span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Year: </span>2000</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-2 text-center thumb-table-cell">
                <span class="eq-table-new text-center">Fake City, USA</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 text-center thumb-table-cell">
                <span class="eq-table-new text-center"><span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Price: </span>$900</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 table_details_new"><span>Descriptive details</span></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- results-panel-new -->
</a>
```

I can get the image, Year, Location, and Price by doing a variation of this:

```
ModelYear = results[0].div.find("div",{"class":"col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-1 text-center thumb-table-cell"}).span.text
```

How do I get the very first href from `results[0]`?

Comment: what about `html_source.a['href']`?

Comment: That's giving me an href, but one that occurs much earlier on the page. The reason for `results` is to isolate down to the listings that I care about.

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: I got that error when doing the first line `results_list = BeautifulSoup(results[0], "html.parser")` so results_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on chat discussion, the `href` link looks available in simply: `results[0]['href']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_all( , href=True)`

e.g:

```
results[0].find_all('a', href=True)[0]
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `results = html_source.findAll("a",{"onclick":"googleTag('click-listings-item-image');"}, href=True)[0]` might work

Comment: Unfortunately no. Thanks for the help so far. I'll just keep trying stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is returning an `a` tag element as you can see shown in print out. So yes, you simply directly access the href with `results[0]['href']`.  You can also tell this as the entire panel (the card displaying the listing) on the page is a clickable element. If you wanted to make this clearer you could change your selector for results to `#js_thumb_view ~ a`. This is also a faster selector.

```
results = html_source.select('#js_thumb_view ~ a')
```

Then all links, for example, with

```
links = [result['href'] for result in results]
```